# Understanding Ruby code from Puppet module openstack/nova

Tags: ruby

I do not know Ruby very well and was hoping someone could help me understand some of what this bit of code is doing.

```
newproperty(:value, :array_matching => :all) do
    desc 'The value of the setting to be defined.'
    def insync?(is)
      return true if @should.empty?
      return false unless is.is_a? Array
      return false unless is.length == @should.length
      return (
        is & @should == is or
        is & @should.map(&:to_s) == is
      )
end
```

I am not sure at all what this line ...

```
newproperty(:value, :array_matching => :all) do
```

... is doing. Is defining a function that accepts two parameters: *value* and *array_matching*? It is a loop? And I do not understand what the *:array_matching => :all* is all about.

Next is ...

```
    desc 'The value of the setting to be defined.'
```

... Is this some sort of built in documentation? Next is this bit:

```
    def insync?(is)
      return true if @should.empty?
      return false unless is.is_a? Array
      return false unless is.length == @should.length
      return (
        is & @should == is or
        is & @should.map(&:to_s) == is
      )
```

I guess that a function called "insync" is being defined. Not sure what the '?' means.  Also I guess @should is some global variable declared in the parent scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to make assumptions and answer this as best I can from the info provided.

1. You probably have a function `newproperty(x, y)` <- accepts 2 arguments, somewhere in the associated model or helper. It's taking those inputs from some user interaction that assigns the `:value` and the `:array_matching => :all` is based on that `:value`.
2. `desc` is not a native Ruby function. It must be defined somewhere. For instance, this code would run:

`def desc(x)
  puts x
end`

`desc 'The value of the setting to be defined.'`

It's a little unconventional but it would work.

3. The ? in `def insync?(is)` is part of the function name. Ruby is intended to be a very English-like language and since many functions evaluate to true or false, it's easier to read sometimes when you just make your function a question in itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still do not understand what the '=>' means in the parameter declaration in the newproperty subroutine. :)

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure so I searched for it and found this identical resource. It looks like it's a unique property to puppet called 'namevar'.
http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/11/25/fun-with-providers/
cntrl f to the section 'Namevars are unique little snowflakes'